# OpenID provider endpoint does not match discovered OpenID provider endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, openid

Quite honestly, this is my first time developing openID app so I'm unclear on terms and what nots but here it goes... I'm trying to use openID with [nodeJS openID plugin](https://github.com/havard/node-openid) but I'm having below error.

`OpenID provider endpoint in assertion response does not match discovered OpenID provider endpoint`

After digging through the source code I believe this is because I have

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=gmail.com&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns....`

as authentication URL but response come back with out `source=gmail.com` as below

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns....`

I'm simply using posted sample code in the plugin's website so I believe my implementation is correct, however I'm not so confident in openID identifier "gmail.com" in below code. Am I suppose to pass in another string for Goggle which does not set source URL attribute?  if that is the case where can I find list of other openID providers' identifiers?

> ```
>     relyingParty.authenticate(identifier, false, function(error, authUrl) {
>         if (error) {
>           res.writeHead(200);
>           res.end('Authentication failed: ' + error.message);
>         } else if (!authUrl) {
>           res.writeHead(200);
>           res.end('Authentication failed');
>         } else {
>           res.writeHead(302, { Location: authUrl });
>           res.end();
>         }
>     });
> ```

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in `node-openid` which has been fixed. Version 0.5.6 (or later) is available on `npm` and does not have this bug.